# Merge every two vertices in a loop

Tags: modeling

So I have a long loop of vertices. And I want to make each 2 vertices to blend into 1 like shown in image.
[image: Problem]
Currently I have a situation like on left(but much longer). However, I need to get situation as visile on right. Selecting every 2 vertices and merging them is long and exhausting process. I was wondering if there is a way to do it faster, in loop.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With the ***Edge Select*** mode enabled select the whole edge with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>RMB</kbd>, then go to ***Select***-->***Checker Deselect***. Set it up to select every second edge segment, then press <kbd>X</kbd>-->***Edge Collapse***.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Since [2.77-rc1](https://developer.blender.org/rB0a11831) the same can be achieved via *Select Shortes Path* where you'd only have to select the first and last Edge and then use *Mesh* > *Vertices* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>V</kbd> > *Merge* <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>M</kbd>, selecting *Collapse* as merge type. It might give some different or even faster results with more complex Topology as you can *Use Topology Distance* (Find the minimum number of steps, ignoring spatial distance).

[image: Select Shortest Path]

Comment: May be also useful. I will try to see whether I can use the first method or this one:)